# DB Mail could not sent mail to the recipients because of the mail server failure in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbmail, sqlmail

I have tried to send database mail but the following issue occurs.

The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. 
(Sending Mail using Account 3 (2018-11-13T13:05:31).

Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. 
(A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond).)

I have done the few configuration as per suggestion in google search but still the same issue occurs.

Below are the steps which I have performed so far.

1. I have enabled is_broker_enabled
2. Enabled inbound and outbound rules for both 465 and 587 ports
3. Ran the following stored procedure

   sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE
   GO

[image]

Comment: This definitely won't work with windows authentication. Use Basic authentication. Then you need to ensure that your gmail account is configured to accept emails from this server. Does this help?https://mathaywardhill.com/2017/03/01/setting-up-database-mail-to-use-my-gmail-account/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have not face any error while troubleshoot Gmail SMTP server connection. The Telnet smtp.gmail.com prompt showed the message like "Connecting to smtp.gmail.com..." for few minutes and closed automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately the page I linked is only half useful. It doesn't tell you what a _successful_ telnet test looks like. Your test actually _failed_ - it timed out. You're meant to see a screen that says 'connected'. Something like this: https://mailtrap.io/blog/2016-07-26-how-to-test-smtp-server . I have deleted my other comment because that page is so useless!

Comment: To reiterate: you cannot connect to gmail. The issue is at the network level. You need to investigate firewalls etc.

Comment: facing the same issue, tried all the suggested answer that can found in the web, but no chance to get through. Wonder if you manage to find the solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with Basic authentication,
IN User Name: Your mail ID.
Password: Your Gmail Password.

Comment: @Vengat - Pretty sure this is the right answer. I believe you'll need to turn on access for less secure apps on your Gmail account though: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @Bridge i have enabled that option in both sender and receiver mails.

Comment: @Vengat Can you Try port 465 After entering Email and Password?

Comment: @BhargavJPatel tried those combination but same issue.

Comment: Do you get _exactly_ the same error message no matter what you try?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, exactly same error occurs repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions worked for me, other than making sure you do NOT have SSL ticked and Anonymous Authentication ticked only.

[image]